# Eigendecomposition and Diagonalization of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Is a matrix diagonalizable if and only if it has an eigendecomposition?

If not, can you give an example of a diagonalizable matrix which doesn't have an eigendecomposition, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and if there are vector $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ each of which is an eigenvector of $M$ and such that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $M$, if $P$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose columns are the $v_k$'s, then $P^{-1}MP$ is a diagonal matrix.

And if $M$ is diagonalisable and $P$ is an invertible matrix such that $P^{-1}MP$ is a diagonal matrix, then the columns of $P$ are a basis of eigenvectors of $M$.

Comment: Can you give a source for this? I would imagine it depends on the field the matrix is over

Comment: For what exactly?

Comment: In the first part, how do we know that P is invertable?
In the second part, how do we know that M only scales the columns of P?

Comment: @JacKeown Because its columns are a basis, and therefore linearly independent. So, $\det P\ne0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah yes. I see now.